# If input has value and radio button is checked remove disabled class from anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to achieve condition, when input has value greater than 1 and radio button is checked then remove disabled class from the anchor.

This is my code

```
<input name="age" id="age" type="text">
<input name="education" type="radio" value="univeristy">

<a href="#" id="diploma" class="btn disabled">Calculate</a>


    $("input").keyup(function () {
        if ($("#age").val().length > 1  && $('input[name=education]:checked')) {

            $("#diploma").removeClass("disabled");

        } else {
             $("#diploma").addClass("disabled");
        }
      });
```

It is triggering after input has value without checking radio is checked.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('input[name=education]:checked')` will always return true, you need to check the object's `length` property: `$('input[name=education]:checked').length`

Answer (score 0):

Use prop('checked') to check radio, refer code below,

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("input").keyup(function () {
        if ($("#age").val().length > 1 && $("input[name='education'][value='univeristy']").prop("checked")) {

            $("#diploma").removeClass("disabled");
            console.log("Removed class 'disabled'");

        } else {
             $("#diploma").addClass("disabled");
             console.log("Added class 'disabled'");
        }
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input name="age" id="age" type="text">
<input name="education" type="radio" value="univeristy">

<a href="#" id="diploma" class="btn disabled">Calculate</a>
</body>
```

Run this code and see console log.

Comment: Edited the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `:checked` [is fine](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/). But it doesn't return a boolean. You need to check that it returns an element. `$(':prop').length > 0` (or using `prop('checked')`). 
Some other stuff you need to change.

1. The condition should not be on the `$("#age").val().length` but on the `$("#age").val()` itself.
2. Use checkbox, not radiobutton. radiobutton is  used to choose one option from others, not to set true/false.
3. You need to check the values on input `keyup`, but also on change of the radio (or checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
    if ($("#age").val().length > 1  && $("input[name='education']").is(':checked')) {

        $("#diploma").removeClass("disabled");

    } else {
         $("#diploma").addClass("disabled");
    }
  });
```